# Why my java code of UVA online judge 100 puzzle shows runtime error in verdict

Tags: java, algorithm

I was trying to submit solution for UVA online judge problem 100. I wrote the code in java and it showed correct results for the test cases. But the verdict by the judge said that it showed runtime error. Can anyone help me why does it happen? Here is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class UVA100 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        while(sc.hasNext())
        {
            int a=sc.nextInt();
            int b=sc.nextInt();
            int start=a<b?a:b;
            int end=a*b/start;
            int maxcycle=0;
            for(int i=start;i<=end;i++)
            {
                int n=i;
                int count=0;
                while(n!=1)
                {
                    if(n%2==0)
                        n=n/2;
                    else
                        n=3*n+1;
                    count++;
                }
                if(count>maxcycle)
                    maxcycle=count+1;
            }
            System.out.println(start+" "+end+" "+maxcycle);
        }

    }

}
```

Here is the URL of the [Problem](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=3&page=show_problem&problem=36)

Comment: Hint: some cycles have elements that exceed the maximum capacity of ints.

Comment: The main problem is i think the outer while loop is not exiting when the input has reached to end. Do you know how can i exit the outer while loop after processing all inputs

Comment: The judge is also telling something like that. Your submission with number 15373324 for the problem 100 - The 3n + 1 problem has failed with verdict Runtime error.

This means that the execution of your program didn't finish properly. Remember to always terminate your code with the exit code 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) RTE problem**

Your n will overflow and become negative. That itself doesn't cause RTE (run time error) as some suggested. Nevertheless in next loop, negative n will now converge to 0:

```
while(n!=1)
{
    if(n%2==0)
        n=n/2;
    else
        n=3*n+1;
    count++;
}
```

Once n becomes 0, it will stay 0, hence endless loop and RTE.

**2) TLE problem**

Once you have resolve this problem you will receive TLE (time limit exceeded) verdict, as you need to improve the speed of your algorithm. Current problem is that you keep recalculating the same values over and over again. You need to use memoization, refer to next link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization